# Errors initializing array in C

Tags: c, arrays, c-preprocessor

I tried to run this code:

```
#define ROW_CNT 8;
#define COLUMN_CNT 24;
#define FIRST_COLUMN 2;

unsigned int volume[ROW_CNT][COLUMN_CNT][ROW_CNT];
```

but I get the following errors:

> expected identifier or '(' before ']' token

Why is that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Take off the semicolons on your #defines.

The #define directives are handled by the [preprocessing stage](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_preprocessor) of compilation, which is all about text substitution.  So, whenever the preprocessor performs text substitution, your program becomes

```
unsigned int volume[8;][24;][2;];
```

which isn't valid C.

Answer (score 3):

```
#define ROW_CNT 8; 
#define COLUMN_CNT 24; 
#define FIRST_COLUMN 2;
```

should be

```
#define ROW_CNT 8
#define COLUMN_CNT 24
#define FIRST_COLUMN 2
```

semicolons should **not** be used for #define

Answer (score 1):

A pre-processor definition, such as `ROW_CNT`, replaces any instances of the identifier in your code with the value it's defined as being. Therefore once the pre-processor has expanded your macros, your code will look like:

```
unsigned int volume[8;][24;][2;];
```

As you can see, the semicolon is included after 8, 24 and 2, since that's how you defined `ROW_CNT`, `COLUMN_COUNT` and `FIRST_COUNT` to be, and that's obviously not valid C syntax.

Remove the semicolons from the end of your `#define`s and the code will compile.